# Set URL to a different get value in PHP

Tags: php, url, dynamic

I have a simple question. How can I set the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) from:

```
.../.../index.php?xyz
```

to:

```
.../.../index.php?abc
```

?

I want to do this dynamically, so I don't want to change it to the specific URL.

Comment: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: but str_replace() doesnt change the url, right?

Comment: Depends on your implementation (not supplied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parse_url()` to manipulate urls, like this:

```
$url = ".../.../index.php?xyz";
$components = parse_url($url);
$new_url = $components['path'] . "?abc";
echo $new_url;
```

Output:

```
.../.../index.php?abc
```

Here's the reference:

- [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: @Tom291 Happy to hear. Cheers! :)